# What can I use to replace a button battery cover?

Tags: personal-care

I have lost the battery cover on my mini tens machine and the machine wont work without it.  The machine isn't sold anymore so I can't get a replacement part.

Comment: Hi Allyrose, Welcome to Lifehacks. We hope you enjoy sharing information and ideas. Visit [Tour] and [Help] to find out more about our site and how best to participate.

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough detail for the best ideas to solve your problem. Edit your question to tell us more about what a tens machine is and does. Who made the device? Pictures and diagrams that you can show is will also help get you a workable answer. Without enough information, your question could be ignored.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of an other 'missing cover' question but the 'does not work' seems different. But it needs details.

Comment: Does the unit work if you press the batteries in? If not, please attach a photo of the battery case, so we can see whether there are electrical connections that need to be handled.

Comment: Can you add a photo for us to better understand the problem.

Comment: Related - https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/10710/6973

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on the design of the device. If the cover is part of the electric circuit, it gets more complicated.

To find out if this is the case: does the device work when you insert the battery and hold it in place with your finger? Then the cover isn't part of the electric circuit, and this should work:

1. Find some non-corrugated cardboard.
2. Cut this to the shape of the battery cover. Depending on the thickness of the cover and the cardboard, you may need multiple layers.
3. Glue the layers together.
4. Place the battery, put the cardboard on top, hold in place with duct tape.